# AND multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, function

```js
function andMultipleExpr(){
  let logicalAnd;
  let i;
  for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
    logicalAnd =  arguments[i] && arguments[i+1];
  }
  return logicalAnd;
}

console.log(andMultipleExpr(true, true, false, false));
```

What I am expecting is to execute this code: *true&&true&&false&&false* and that should return **false**.

How to make that work in js? 
Thanks

Comment: I am just hesitating. I want to be sure if my idea is well formulated. If there is a better way, please suggest.

Comment: What should be the output when Troothy values are used instead of booleans? i.e. `andMultipleExpr(1, 1, 0, 0)` or `andMultipleExpr(1, 1, 1, 1)`

Comment: Also what should be the output of `andMultipleExpr()` (Calling the function with no parameters)?

Comment: well, those cases need to be taken into account as well. :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.every` on all the passed arguments to check if they all are true;

```js
function andMultipleExpr(...a) {
  if(a.length === 0) return false; // return false when no argument being passed
  return a.every(Boolean);
}

console.log(andMultipleExpr(true, true, false)); // should return false
console.log(andMultipleExpr(true, true, true)); // should return true
```

Comment: Could replace `e => e === true` with `Boolean`

Comment: @nickzoum this would match all truthy values, OP is strictly comparing `true`.

Comment: @Archie - No, they're comparing truthy/falsy. There's no `===` in the OP's code. Your `every` idea is **spot on**, though. But just `.every(e => e)` does the job.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes just noticed that. Updated the answer already. Thanks :)

Comment: If you add a helper function: `const isTrue = x => x === true` (or `x => !!x` for all truthy values), you can compress your solution into `return arguments.every(isTrue)`. Which to me seems just beautiful.

Answer (score 8):

You need to

1. Start out with `logicalAnd` set to `true`
2. Use `logicalAnd` when updating it, rather than using two entries from `arguments`

The minimal change is:

```js
function andMultipleExpr(){
    let logicalAnd = true; // ***
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        logicalAnd = logicalAnd && arguments[i]; // ***
    }
    return logicalAnd;
}
console.log(andMultipleExpr(true, true, false, false));
```

But [mbojko's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59749611/157247) has the advantage of short-circuiting (stopping the loop when it first finds a falsy value), which seems like a good idea.

Since you're using ES2015+, you should probably use a rest parameter rather than `arguments`, and you can use a `for-of` loop:

```js
function andMultipleExpr(...flags) {
    let logicalAnd = true;
    for (const flag of flags) {
        logicalAnd = logicalAnd && flag;
    }
    return logicalAnd;
}
console.log(andMultipleExpr(true, true, false, false));
```

You can also short-circuit that in keeping with [mbojko's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59749611/157247)

```js
function andMultipleExpr(...flags) {
    for (const flag of flags) {
        if (!flag) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
console.log(andMultipleExpr(true, true, false, false));
```

Some people might throw `reduce` at this, but [Archie's `every` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59749569/157247) is much better. (But since your comparison isn't strict, I'd just make it `.every(flag => flag)`.)

Comment: Thanks. That makes more sense to me :-)

Comment: There is no need to add a second parameter in the reduce statement in this case, getting the first parameter by default would also work.

Comment: @nickzoum - Only if we can assume that the function will never be called with no arguments, since `[].reduce((a,b)=>a && b)` throws.

Answer (score 5):

Early returns should make the code both more efficient and shorter:

```
function andMultipleExpr() {
  for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (!arguments[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a very **short way** using **ES6** `Array.prototype.reduce`

```js
let andMultipleExpr = (...args) => args.reduce((a, b) => a && b);

console.log(andMultipleExpr(true, true, false, false));
```

For more explanation about reduce function, please read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: If you're doing to use an array method, it's **much** better to use `every` like [Archie did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59749569/157247) than `reduce`. Simpler, and it short circuits.

Comment: It is true. But let us stay now he wants but **LOGICAL OR ||** now with the reduce, it will just be change **&&** to **||**

Comment: Or `every` to `some`. Still simpler. Still short-circuits.

Answer (score 2):

You could take [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and return the last value.

This approach returns the real result of [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND).

By using the approach, a short circuit is made for the first found falsy value. Then the iteration stops.

```js
function andMultipleExpr(...args) {
    var result; // any return value is configurable for empty args
    args.every(v => result = v);
    return result;
}

console.log(andMultipleExpr(true, true, false, false));
console.log(andMultipleExpr(true, true, 1, 2));
console.log(andMultipleExpr(true, 0, 1, 2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want to hear what went wrong with the loop:

> ```
> for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
>   logicalAnd =  arguments[i] && arguments[i+1];
> }
> ```

1. this loop stores the `&&` of the last two items it encounters. In the ideal case it would `&&` together the last two elements of the array (which is already not what you need)
2. on top of that at the end of the loop `i=arguments.length-1`, it will check the last element of the array, and `i+1` is the element "after" the last one, which is `undefined`. In terms of logical relations, it is considered `false`, but `&&` produces the value itself in such case, and that is why the function returns `undefined` all the time (this could have been mentioned that in the question).

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

> `expr1 && expr2` : If `expr1` can be converted to `true`, returns `expr2`; else, returns `expr1`.

```js
arr=[true];
console.log("your case:",arr[0] && arr[1]);

console.log("1 && 2:", 1 && 2);
```

---

Instead, you should use `logicalAnd` as an accumulator, which collects the result of `&&`-ing all the previous elements, and a trick what you can use is if the result of a partial `&&` is `false`, it does not matter what the remaining elements are, the end result is going to be `false`, so the loop can stop immediately:

```js
function andMultipleExpr(){
    let logicalAnd = arguments[0] || false;
    for (let i = 1; i < arguments.length && logicalAnd; i++){
        logicalAnd = logicalAnd && arguments[i];
    }
    return logicalAnd;
}

console.log("():",andMultipleExpr());
console.log("(false):",andMultipleExpr(false));
console.log("(true):",andMultipleExpr(true));
console.log("(true,true):",andMultipleExpr(true,true));
console.log("(true, true, false, false):",andMultipleExpr(true, true, false, false));
```

and then you can optimize it towards Archie's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59749569/7916438): the result of `&&`-ing items is `true` if all of the items are `true`, and you do not have to execute a single `&&` operation for calculating the result:

```js
function andMultipleExpr(){
    if(arguments.length===0){
      return false;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
      if(!arguments[i]){
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
}

console.log("():",andMultipleExpr());
console.log("(false):",andMultipleExpr(false));
console.log("(true):",andMultipleExpr(true));
console.log("(true,true):",andMultipleExpr(true,true));
console.log("(true, true, false, false):",andMultipleExpr(true, true, false, false));
```

(In the snippets above I aimed for producing `false` for an empty argument list.)